# Can I add routing for a page in the same file I create the controller?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

for example, can I do this?

```
angular.module('example')
    .controller('fooCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
        'HTML5 Boilerplate',
        'AngularJS',
        'Karma'];
})
    .when('/foo', {
    templateUrl: 'views/foo.html',
    controller: 'FooCtrl'
});
```

I'm asking because the part of the [Yeoman AngularJS generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) that generates routes does not set things up properly, and I'm trying to create a pull request that will fix the issue. JSHint checked the above code, and came back with no errors, so I'm hopeful. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet: I'm on someone else's computer right now, I'll try it when I have the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that won't work, it should be like this

```
angular.module('example',[])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider

})
    .when('/foo', {
    templateUrl: 'views/foo.html',
    controller: 'fooCtrl'
})
.controller('fooCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
        'HTML5 Boilerplate',
        'AngularJS',
        'Karma'];
});
```